# Is there a way to restart a for loop after it has completed iterating?

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

I have a parameter set before a very complicated nested *for* loop.

Once the for loop is completed, I would like to set *p* to *p+1* and then restart the loop at the first iteration. I can do the first fairly easily with an if statement, but is there a way to restart the loop from the first iteration? Currently, it just stops after setting i to 1.

```
p <- 19
a <- matrix()
source <- c(1:420)
for (i in 1:length(source)) {
  a[i] <- p + i
  if (i==length(source)) {
    p <- p+1
    i <- 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a while loop and reset your loop count variable as you are doing.

Comment: In practice what you probably want is to nest your for loop over i inside a for loop over p

Answer (score 1):

The usual pattern people use for this is to nest for loops, one for each axis.  I don't know if there's something that prevents it from working specifically in R but it would probably look something like this.

```
a <- matrix()
source <- c(1:420)
for (p in 19:20 ) {
  for (i in 1:length(source)) {
    a[i] <- p + i
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have yet to try this on my current computer for fear that it will make the code run even slower, but when I switch to a setup that can run for more than an hour without overheating I will keep this in mind.